# How can I count the number of radio boxes selected and validate?

Tags: javascript, validation

So here's what my code does:

it displays 10 sets of radio buttons, each with 2 options. (so 20 radio buttons total). The 10 sets all have different names, but are within the same form. A person can only choose 5 buttons out of the 10. I have a piece of code that disables the radio buttons once 5 are selected. Now I want to prevent people from submitting the form if 4 or less buttons are selected.

Here is an example of the code:

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="index.php" name="buttons" onsubmit="return Validation()">
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="1" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="1" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="2" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="2" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="3" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="3" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="4" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="4" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="5" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="5" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="6" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="6" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="7" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="7" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="8" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="9" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="9" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="9" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="first_button" name="10" />
 <input type="radio" id="button" value="second_button" name="10" />
 </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 function Validation()
 {
 var bol2 = $("input:radio:checked").length;
 if (bol2<=4)
   {
   alert("Please select 5 buttons");
   return false;
   }
 }
```

The code now works. Thanks @Climbage, I looked at other code and figured out what to do

Comment: You cannot use the same id for all of them.  Id attributes must be unique to each page.

Comment: Wait so you already have code that disables the buttons when 5 are selected?  Can you reuse that?

Comment: for each of the button, add a `onclick= {counter++}` method, and use the count to validate

Comment: @roymustang86 : This doesn't do that OP wants

Comment: try to use this if you accept jQuery `$('form input[type=radio]:checked')` or `$('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();`. This must return the number of checked radio inputs. Sorry no time for testing by myself.

Comment: @Andre Yes, jQuery is an option.

Comment: @climbage that disables the buttons. I just want something that doesnt let you submit unless you have at least 5 buttons checked

Comment: @loler I tried that and it returns the value of the first radio button checked, not the count, and it doesn't show all checked radios.

Comment: @user1470755 yes... but... how are you counting to check that 5 are selected?

Comment: @climbage This code comes right after the form.   <script>
              $(\"input:radio\").click(function() {
              var bol = $(\"input:radio:checked\").length >= 5;     
              $(\"input:radio\").not(\":checked\").attr(\"disabled\",bol);
              });
            </script>

Comment: @climbage It was a good idea to look at the other code. I figured out what to do. I replaced the code above with the working code

Comment: see the code and use it http://jsfiddle.net/HzfKq/65/

Answer (score 3):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/BeT4h/

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="buttons" id="form">

<script>
function showTime() {
    var inputs = document.getElementById("form").elements;
    var count  = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio' && inputs[i].checked) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    alert(count);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make 5 of them checked by default.
Put `check='checked'` for every other input. Put in all first_button or second_button.